# Insert after navbar

Tags: typo3

I'm using Typo3 6.2.15 with bootstrap_package.

I have inserted language bar after shopping basket. How to insert after navbar instead?

```
lib.navigation.basket.20 < lib.language
```

Screenshot from DOM: [link](http://prntscr.com/9vyxa8)

Comment: It's not possible to answer this question, as we don't even know your `lib.navigation` markup

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at template EXT:bootstrap_package/Resources/Private/Layouts/Page/Default.html. There you should see the lines

```
<f:render partial="Navigation/Main" arguments="{_all}"/>
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.navigation.breadcrumb"/>
```

You can overwrite this template in TypoScript constants:

```
page.fluidtemplate.layoutRootPath = EXT:yourExt/Resources/Private/Layouts/Page/
```

In the new template you now can make any modifications you want.
The best will be, you create a new TypoScript object for the basket:

```
lib.basket = TEXT
lib.basket.value = whatever
```

Then, you can arrange the contents in the layout template as you wish:

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.basket"/>
<f:render partial="Navigation/Main" arguments="{_all}"/>
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.language"/>
```

Don't assign the TypoScript objects to other TypoScript objects (like you do with "lib.navigation.basket.20 < lib.language"), modify the templates (but do not modify the original templates EXT:bootstrap_package, create your own template storage)!